# Unit test ViewModel class

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

I am trying to write unit test for my ViewModel class.
In this case, I have an activity that when created, it subscribes to my repo (LiveData from viewModel) and retrieves a list of Github repositories from network or database.

What should I be testing here? I tried to write two test methods:

**dontFetchWithoutObservers** which fails with the following:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**fetchWhenObserved** which fails with the following:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here's my ViewModel class:

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val repo: LiveData<Resource<List<Repository>>> = mainRepository.getRepositories()

}
```

And my ViewModel test class:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val mainRepository = mock(MainRepository::class.java)
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() {
        mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mainRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun dontFetchWithoutObservers() {
        verify(mainRepository, never()).getRepositories()
    }

    @Test
    fun fetchWhenObserved() {
        mainViewModel.repo.observeForever(mock())
        verify(mainRepository).getRepositories()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not mocking the `getRepositories`  method and in fact the error you get is: NPE.
Provide a mock for `getRepositories` method.

```
`when`(mainRepository.getRepositories()).thenReturn(YourObject)
```

Also I would go and check the contents of `getRepositories` instead of just verifying that it is being invoked.